# "URLDownloadToFile" not doing anything at all

Tags: c++, cmd

I'm making a program where it checks if the user has the required JRE installed so they are able to run jar files. And, if they don't have it, then it downloads and runs the file for them. However, I keep getting the same error no matter what type of method I find online and apply. It keeps telling me that its unable to find or open the exe. And when I check the download location, it doesn't download anything at all.

Code:

```
 HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, _T("https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u291-b10/d7fc238d0cbf4b0dac67be84580cfb4b/jre-8u291-windows-x64.exe"), _T( "c:\\jre-8u291-windows-x64.exe"), 0, NULL);
 cout << "Download Complete" << endl;
 cout << "Now installing" << endl;
 system("start c:\\jre-8u291-windows-x64.exe");
```

Includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

using namespace std;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: don't have to tag java. and if you already uses `system`, then you can also use `curl` or `wget`

Comment: Odds are you don't have permission to download to the root of C:, but you don't have any error checking so could be anything really. That URL also requires you to sign in.

Comment: Did you check the result HR?

Comment: should i change it to ``c:\\Downloads\\jre-8u291-windows-x64.exe``? will that work

Comment: I had an if condition where HR is equal to S_OK but still got the same output, didn't even print my error message if it ``!= S_OK``

Comment: Can an ordinary user write to C:\ these days? You might be better off with an installer that ships its [own mini JRE](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9). That's out-of-the-box installers with 'modern' JDKS

Comment: Okay, I tried writing it to ``c:\\Downloads\\jre-8u291-windows-x64.exe`` still the same error, no download occurred at all, Where do you recommend i write then?

Comment: i tried the url, it requires login. so i think the download should not work. even downloaded, it should be some html instead.

Comment: It saves a file for me, with the contents of the sign-in page.

Comment: another possibility is deleted by anti virus software?

Comment: ``1.`` I know it requires a login, so i tried with another exe like ccleaner which doesn't require it and still got the same error

Comment: ``2.`` I didn't get the contents of a sign-in page so thats strange

Comment: ``3.`` I have Windows Defender and Bit Defender and none of them detected anything or when off, especially when Bit Defender is strict and deletes almost anything

Comment: @pikoloy871 `URLDownloadToFile()` is notoriously buggy. Use `InternetReadFile()` directly instead (see [Downloading Resources from the WWW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/http-sessions#downloading-resources-from-the-www)). Or use a 3rd party library, like [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/).